# Bottom Sheet with fab partly outside the borders

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement bottom sheet that will overlap exactly a view not a 
whole screen. Desirable

[image: end position].

But here is actual result

**end position**

[image: end position].

What I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code. I want to overlap Textview with id content_to_overlap.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#399"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Text1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
    android:background="#399"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Text2Text2Text2Text2" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn2"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_to_overlap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="#B44"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text3" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:background="#8FF0"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-48dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This is a [start position](http://cs5-3.4pda.to/8354551.png)

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Code Below is not perfect but is provided to give you an idea
Use `anchor` for fab

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#399"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Text1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
    android:background="#399"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Text2Text2Text2Text2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn2"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_to_overlap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="#B44"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="48dp"
       app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:background="#8FF0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text3" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:anchor="@id/content_to_overlap" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```